# Why does typing "qi" into my pinyin keyboard produce the trans flag?

Tags: meaning

I use an online Pinyin keyboard which suggests emojis based on what I write. For example, if I write "开心“, a smiley face is suggested. I've noticed, if I type "qi", the trans flag emoji pops up. I looked up the word for "transgender", which I found translated as "变性人“. I wasn't able to find any trans-related idea with the word "qi", nor have I been able to find which specific character the keyboard is associating with "trans".

Does anyone know which word the computer might be associating with "trans"?

Comment: If I didn't make a mistake, qi is 旗's pinyin, so it shows you a flag, but I've no clue why it uses "trans" flag for presentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qi reffers to 旗 which means a flag in chinese

Trans is a difficult question in china now

because lgbt groups are not treated equally

so no clue for the trans thing

but qi means flag